# Synchronization confusion in Java Thread Example

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Mythread extends Thread{
    Parenthesis p = new Parenthesis();
    String s1;
    Mythread(String s){
        s1 = s;
    }
    public void run(){
        p.display(s1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mythread t1 = new Mythread("Atul");
        Mythread t2 = new Mythread("Chauhan");
        Mythread t3 = new Mythread("Jaikant");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

}

class Parenthesis{
    public void display(String str){
        synchronized (str) {
            System.out.print("("+str);  
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //System.out.print("("+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.print(")");
        }


}
}
```

I am getting output like (Atul(Chauhan(Jaikant))). As per my knowledge each Thread's object has own copy of Parenthesis's object that's why getting output like (Atul(Chauhan(Jaikant))).So  even synchronizing the method display() will not produce the result like (Atul)(Chauhan)(Jaikant). So if I want desired output I have to make syncronized static display() method. Correct me if I am worng.

Comment: You could as well share the same Parenthesis instance between all 3 threads (and make the display method synchronized, of course) if you want to avoid a static method.

Comment: So what i explained above is correct@Fildor

Comment: You could do it the way you said. But it is not the best one. Actually there are multiple ways to get the desired result. When it comes to synchronizing, you should keep it as simple as possible. And as Peter stated correctly: Be sure you _really need_ multithreading after all.

Comment: Actually my friend asked me this question. This question was asked to him in the interview and interviewer told him that explain the program and expected output.- Fildor

Answer (score 2):

If you want output like (Atul)(Chauhan)(Jaikant) you need all threads to synchronize on the same object.

Example:

```
class Parenthesis{
    static final String syncObject = "Whatever";

    public void display(String str){
        synchronized (syncObject) {
            System.out.print("("+str);  
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //System.out.print("("+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.print(")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You could just use synchronized(Parenthesis.class). Without the need for additional sync object

Comment: +1 or don't use threads and just use a loop.  You should only use multiple threads when it is simpler/better than using just one thread.